# Collections.sort() but read from right to left

Tags: java

I have an arrayList named Dates that is like this :

```
     "12-07-2017;
      13-07-2017;
      12-08-2017;
      11-08-2019;"
```

Normally the Collections.sort(dates) is :

```
   "11-08-2019;
    12-07-2017;
    12-08-2017;
    13-07-2017"
```

But I want it to read from the right to the left , and not from the left to right in a way that Collections.sort(dates) should be like this :

```
   "12-07-2017;
    13-07-2017;
    12-08-2017;
    11-08-2019"
```

Comment: Convert to `LocalDate` and sort?

Comment: But is there anyWay of reading from right to left ? That would be way more easy.

Comment: You could write your own Comparator

Comment: You *don't* just want to read right-to-left. If you did, `13-07-2017` would be before `13-07-2008`. You need to compare each of the three parts of those strings separately, in a custom comparator.

Comment: How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an `ArrayList` of `String` objects such that each string is formatted as `dd-MM-yyyy` called `dateStrings`.

First of all create the `SimpleDateFormat` object which will serve as a basis for converting the `String` to a `Date` object and back.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Then convert your `ArrayList` of `String` objects into an `ArrayList` of `Date` objects.

```
ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
for (String dateString : dateStrings) {
    try {
        dates.add(dateFormat.parse(dateString));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Sort your `Date` objects using `Collections.sort()` (no `Collections.reverseOrder()` comparator needed as it sorts in ascending order).

```
Collections.sort(dates);
```

Finally convert your `ArrayList` of `Date` objects back into an `ArrayList` of `String` objects.

```
ArrayList<String> orderedDateStrings = new ArrayList<>();
for (Date date : dates) {
    orderedDateStrings.add(dateFormat.format(date));
}
```

You now have the `ArrayList` of `Strings` `orderedDateStrings` with the strings in your required order.

Do not forget to import all of `java.util.ArrayList, java.util.Collections, java.util.Date, java.text.ParseException, java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Never mind it won't be , but if I have the dates : 25-07-2017 for example and 19-07-2017 it will put 25-07 first

Comment: Why do you need the `Collections.reverseOrder()` ?

Comment: Sorry I made a few mistakes in my code, fixing them now.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are sorting date representations lexicographically.

You have two options of doing this:

- Use [`sort` method that takes `Comparator<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)), and pass a comparator that parses your dates for comparison, or
- Convert strings to dates, sort them, and convert the results back to `String`s.